# Slick Slider Settings by Class

Tags: wordpress, slick.js, acfpro

I'm making a WordPress theme where I use ACF Flexible Content.
One block is to add a slider to the page, and I have added some ACF fields as options that the user can use to customise the slider.

Two of those options are slick slider settings:
They can choose the number of columns (1-3), and the scroll direction (horizontal/vertical).

Is there a way of adding slick settings to a variety of classes without writing sliders for every single one of the combinations? I'd like something along these lines, but this doesn't work:

```js
// base slide that applies to all sliders
$('#slider').slick({
  mobileFirst: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 2000,
  dots: true,
  pauseOnHover: true
});

// if vertical-scroll class add the #slider base settings, PLUS these settings
$('.vertical-scroll').slick({
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true
});

// if one-column class add the #slider base settings, PLUS these settings
$('.one-column').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});

// if two-column class add the #slider base settings, PLUS these settings
$('.two-column').slick({
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 2
});

// if three-column class add the #slider base settings, PLUS these settings
$('.three-column').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```html
<?php
  // acf variables
  $slide_columns = get_sub_field('columns');
  $slide_direction = get_sub_field('direction');
 ?>

<ul id="slider" class"<?php echo $slide_direction; ?> <?php echo $slide_columns; ?>">
  <li class="slide"><?php echo $slide_content; ?></li>
  <li class="slide"><?php echo $slide_content; ?></li>
  <li class="slide"><?php echo $slide_content; ?></li>
  <li class="slide"><?php echo $slide_content; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way using PHP:

```
<script>
  // base slide that applies to all sliders
  $('#slider').slick({
  mobileFirst: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 2000,
  dots: true,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  slidesToShow: <?php echo get_sub_field('columns'); ?>,
  slidesToScroll: <?php echo get_sub_field('direction'); ?>
  });
</script>

<ul id="slider">
  <li class="slide"><?php echo $slide_content; ?></li>
  <li class="slide"><?php echo $slide_content; ?></li>
  <li class="slide"><?php echo $slide_content; ?></li>
  <li class="slide"><?php echo $slide_content; ?></li>
</ul>
```